# Reference to currently executing array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to reference the currently executing array from within an array?

I would like to do the following, for example (I used the $this keyword to clarify what I mean, which I need a substitue for obviously):

```
function somefunction(string $data_string) {
    return array(
        "data" => explode($data_string, "/"),
        "key1" => reset($data_string) !== false ? array_shift($this->"data") : "do something else",
        etc...
    );
}
```

I could of course solve this by doing the following:

```
function somefunction(string $data_string) {
    $var["data"] = explode($data_string, "/");
    $var["key1"] = reset($data_string) !== false ? array_shift($var["data"]) : "do something else";
    etc...
    return $var;
}
```

But it feels as if creating the extra variable $var is unnecessary.

Comment: Where is, and what scope is, `$data` declared?

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud sorry typo it should be $data_string

Comment: No, it's not possible. You're abusing arrays, if you think you need to do this.

Comment: You can try it yourself, just var_dump() or print_r() the result of somefunction() with some testing input array, then ask "i expected this result but i get this instead..."

Comment: You could do the explode before the function and use that as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to work with array, if you are creating that array. I don´t know any language, where it would be possible. If you need something like this, your code design is probably huge mess.
I don´t see anything wrong with "your solution".